# oracle to_char daylight savings

Tags: oracle, dst, to-char

In below, why isn't Daylight savings included in to_char()?  How can i get the time with daylight savings?

```
SELECT systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Adelaide' from dual;
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Adelaide' ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS AM') from dual;

returns

16-OCT-13 07.19.01.165681000 PM AUSTRALIA/ADELAIDE
2013-10-16 06:19:01 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select to_char( systimestamp at time zone 'AUSTRALIA/ADELAIDE', 
'HH24:MI:SS TZR TZD' ) from dual
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Comment: still the time returned doesnt include daylight savings.  it has one hour less compared to systimestamp at time zone 'AUSTRALIA/ADELAIDE'

Comment: @user503647, it looks OK to me- compare the [sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18718) to [this clock](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/australia/south-australia/adelaide/)

Comment: You are right.  Sqlfiddle (oracle 11g R2) returns correct time with daylight savings.  I am running it in oracle sql developer against oracle 10g (10.2.0.4) database.  Am i missing any database configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of outdated timezones files in oracle server.  Adelaide timezones were updated around 2008 or 2007. once timezone files were updated issue got resolved.